# Human Base Mesh Installation

Tags: installation

I have finished installing Blender 3.6 and have eagerly awaited the human base meshes for this software, but I do not know how to install the meshes as assets. I am capable of opening the meshes but not installing them as assets.

If anyone could direct me towards a step by step guide, I would be most appreciative.

Comment: Please don't sign your questions. They get signed automatically with your user card.

Comment: Download the zip file. Unzip it into a folder where your assets are kept. Load the "human_base_meshes_bundle.blend" file into blender and follow the instructions there. That's it!  If you don't know about setting up the asset browser there are lots of YT tutorials online.

Comment: A full answer detailing default asset locations(installation directory / user preferences folder  `datafiles/assets/`) might be useful. But it seems the devs made a real mess here. There are geometry nodes hair preset assets in installation directory `datafiles/assets/` that get completely ignored if one places anything in user preferences folder  `datafiles/assets/`  It's a real pity it's so inconsistent.